# About which matter? or Which matter about? or Which matter is about?

Tags: grammar

Me: What's your opinion?

My friend: About which matter? /Which matter about? /Which matter is about?

Which one should my friend say?

5. On which thing do I put it?
6. Which thing do I put it on?

Are 5 and 6 correct?

Comment: What is your intended meaning for "Which matter about"? I can't understand this phrase.

Comment: @CowperKettle I believe what was meant was *About what?* or *About which matter?*

Comment: As far as the placement of *on*: both versions are acceptable, but the stranded version (i.e. the second one) is more common. The first version sounds strained, like something one might say to try to comply with the long-discredited 'rule' that one 'shouldn't end a sentence with a preposition'.

Comment: The link between the two pairs of examples is unclear. Please [edit] to explain the (single) point of English that you're asking about.

Comment: I've edited my question, can you answer me now.

Comment: "About which matter?" is the only correct version, but would sound very stilted in conversation. As linguisticturn says, it would be much more natural to say "About what?"

Answer (score 1):

A possible dialogue could go like this:

> "I'd like to talk to you about a matter."
>   "About which matter?"

In such a context, and choosing between the three examples you gave, that is the most reasonable answer.

But typically, especially, I think, in North America, the word *that* would be used more often than *which*.

Therefore, the following exchange could also take place:

> "I'd like to talk to you about a matter."
>   "And that matter is about  . . . ?"

This comes close to your third example. Based on this response (which could be given), I *can* see the answer being phrased exactly like your third example, but it would be highly uncommon. (At least as far as I've ever heard.)

I don't believe anybody would ever use the second example, or that it's even grammatical.

As for the second question, both are fine. The first is more formal (or used by anyone who is trying to avoid ending a sentence with a preposition on the mistaken belief that doing so is ungrammatical), while the latter is more common (although not as common as other constructions).

Comment: "I'd like to talk to you about a matter." "And that matter is about  . . . ?" sounds odd to me (although in UK). I'd prefer "What matter is that?" or "What about?" or "What do you want to talk about?" or several other variants.